# idref element in Spring framework reference

Tags: java, spring

In the `idref` element in the Spring framework reference where it [says](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/):

> The above bean definition snippet is exactly equivalent (at runtime) to the following snippet

```
 <bean id="client" class="...">
     <property name="targetName" value="theTargetBean" />
 </bean>
```

should actually be

```
<bean id="client" class="...">
    <property name="targetName" ref="theTargetBean" />
</bean>
```

right?

Comment: seems like it, please consider reporting the issue to the contributors

Comment: The sentence before the sample says it: "The idref element is simply an error-proof way to pass the id (*string value - not a reference*) of another bean in the container to a <constructor-arg/> or <property/> element."

Comment: @rockon, I've added the answer, you might look at

Answer (score 0):

**No, they are totally different.**

In the first case, you are pointing out to a `String` value `"theTargetBean"` which will be transformed into a corresponding instance depending on a type of the property and processors that will be parsing this configuration file. Consider some *pseudocode* for better understanding:

```
class Client {
    String theTargetBean = targetBeanMetaInformation.getName();
}
```

The second case refers to a bean with a name of `theTargetBean`. It is a reference to the `theTargetBean` bean.

```
class Client {
    Target theTargetBean = targetBeanMetaInformation.getInstanceFrom();
}
```